# How to add validator in drop down In flutter

Tags: flutter, dropdownbox, flutter-dropdownbutton

im new in flutter and I'm using drop down in the record fields but I want to make if the user did not fill the drop down and the user click the save button, it will show the "Please fill up the drop down" but in the code, im trying to add "validator" but it shows "The named parameter 'validator' isn't defined.". Can anyone know how to fix that? Please help. Thank you

```
String selectExpense;

class RecordExpense extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RecordExpenseState createState() => _RecordExpenseState();
}

class _RecordExpenseState extends State<RecordExpense> {
  //DatabaseReference _ref;
  final date = TextEditingController();
  final currency = TextEditingController();
  final category = TextEditingController();
  final amount = TextEditingController();
  final description = TextEditingController();
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final databaseReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String _email, _password;

  Future<String> getCurrentUID() async {
    Future.value(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser);
    //return uid;
  }

  @override

  String selectCurrency;

  final expenseSelected = TextEditingController();
  final currencySelected = TextEditingController();



  List <String> expensecategories = [
    "Food",
    "Social Life",
    "Transportation",
    "Beauty",
    "Household",
    "Education",
    "Health",
    "Gift",
    "Other"
  ];

  List <String> currencycategories = [
    "IDR",
    "MYR",
    "USD",
    "CNY"
  ];


  DateTime _selectedDate;

  void initState(){
    //_ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Transaction');
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    //CollectionReference collect= firestore.collection("TransactionExpense");


    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User user =_auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user.uid;


    String dates;
    String amounts;
    String selectExpenses;
    String descriptions;
    return new Form(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),

          child: Container(
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        validator: (input) {
                          if (input.isEmpty) return 'Please fill up the text fields';
                        },
                        cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                        controller: date,
                        onTap: () {
                          _selectDate(context);
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: getTranslated((context), "date_text"),
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
                          hintText: getTranslated((context), "date_hint"),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(

                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget> [
                        new Expanded(child: new DropDownField(
                          controller: currencySelected,
                          labelText: getTranslated((context), "currency_hint"),
                          enabled: true,
                          itemsVisibleInDropdown: 4,
                          items: currencycategories,
                          onValueChanged: (dynamic value) {
                            selectCurrency = value;
                          },
                          value: selectCurrency,
                          required: false,
                        ),
                          flex: 2,
                        ),
                        new SizedBox(
                          width: 10.0,
                        ),
                        new Expanded(child:
                        TextFormField(
                          validator: (input) {
                            if (input.isEmpty) return 'Please fill up the text fields';
                          },
                          cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                          controller: amount,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: getTranslated((context), "amount_text"),
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
                            hintText: getTranslated((context), "amount_text"),
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(

                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                            ),
                          ),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        ),)

                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: secondary),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                        ),
                        child: DropDownField(
                          controller: expenseSelected,
                          hintText: getTranslated((context), "category_hint"),
                          labelText: getTranslated((context), "category_text"),
                          enabled: true,
                          itemsVisibleInDropdown: 4,
                          items: expensecategories,
                          onValueChanged: (dynamic value) {
                            selectExpense = value;
                          },
                          value: selectExpense,
                          required: false,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Container(
                      //padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        validator: (input) {
                          if (input.isEmpty) return 'Please fill up the text fields';
                        },
                        cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                        controller: description,
                        maxLines: 2,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: getTranslated((context), "description_text"),
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
                          hintText: getTranslated((context), "description_expense"),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(

                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 25.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: ElevatedButton(

                                onPressed: () async {
                                  if(!_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                                    return;
                                  }
                                  _formKey.currentState.save();
                                  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userID).collection('TransactionExpense').add({
                                        'date': date.text,
                                        'currency': selectCurrency,
                                        'amount': amount.text,
                                        'category': selectExpense,
                                        'description': description.text,
                                      });
                                      date.text = "";
                                      amount.text = "";
                                      description.text = "";


                                  /*
                                UserCredential _user =
                                    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
                                String _uid = _user.user.uid;

                                 */

                                  //await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('TransactionExpense').doc(_uid).set({

/*
                            final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth
                                .instance;
                            final User user = _auth.currentUser;
                            final uid = user.uid;

                            await DatabaseService().updateData(
                                uid, date.text, amount.text,
                                selectExpense, description.text);
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                            */
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                    getTranslated((context), "save_button").toUpperCase(), style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                )),
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                  padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                      EdgeInsets>(EdgeInsets.all(15)),
                                  foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty
                                      .all<Color>(Colors.white),
                                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty
                                      .all<Color>(Colors.pink),
                                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                      RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                            15.0),
                                        side: BorderSide(color: secondary)
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),

                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 20, height: 10),
                            Expanded(
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  clearButton();
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                    getTranslated((context), "clear_button").toUpperCase(), style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14
                                )),
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                  padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                      EdgeInsets>(EdgeInsets.all(15)),
                                  foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty
                                      .all<Color>(Colors.white),
                                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty
                                      .all<Color>(Colors.pink),
                                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                      RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                    RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                            15.0),
                                        side: BorderSide(color: secondary)
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ),
      );
  }

  void clearButton(){
    date.clear();
    amount.clear();
    category.clear();
    description.clear();
  }
  _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime newSelectedDate = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: _selectedDate != null ? _selectedDate : DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2000),
        lastDate: DateTime(2040),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Theme(
            data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
                primary: secondary,
                onPrimary: Colors.black,
                surface: primary,
                onSurface: Colors.white,
              ),
              dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
            ),
            child: child,
          );
        });

    if (newSelectedDate != null) {
      _selectedDate = newSelectedDate;
      date
        ..text = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_selectedDate)
        ..selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(
            offset: date.text.length,
            affinity: TextAffinity.upstream));
    }
  }
}
class AlwaysDisabledFocusNode extends FocusNode {
  @override
  bool get hasFocus => false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validator parameter is available only on FormField classes, these clasess end with FormForm Field in the flutter sdk.

To get this to work you should replace `DropDownButton` with `DropDownButtonFormField` widget to get access to the validator.

Check the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButtonFormField-class.html) for more information

Comment: but when I change the into DropDownBUttonFormFields, it shows redline from controller to required. it shows The named parameter 'controller' isn't defined and others error message. how to fix?

Comment: Remove controller, you dont need a controller with FormFields, When you use a form controller is created automatically

Comment: when I try to remove, the label text also show error The named parameter 'labelText' isn't defined, The named parameter 'enabled' isn't defined, The named parameter 'itemsVisibleInDropdown' isn't defined, the named parameter 'onValueChanged' isn't defined and The named parameter 'required' isn't defined. I got this red line

Comment: Please read the doc above, is `onValueChanged` is `onChanged` like all other FormFields. labelText is set in decoration  like all other FormFIeld. Your question about the validator has been answered. If you have other question about Dropdown you can ask a new question.

Comment: ok I already changed it to onChanged but why I can't see the value inside the dropdown?

Comment: Set the value parameter and make sure you call setState